# Xamarin Forms: Label text sometimes showing only first word on UI

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, label

I am using `FlowListView` for showing multiple items in a row and label to show the content on UI. My problem is label text sometimes showing only a part of the data. There is enough space on the UI, but sometimes it only shows a single word from the data. It is also happening when scrolling. Initially show full content, after scroll down and coming back only the first word of the content is present in the UI.

I have uploaded a sample on [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15OUzjLgDqeZT55iej6iINGTpVw79k8H4). The first content is `Act of Contrition`, but sometimes it shows only `Act` on UI.

Also, there is a problem with the expected UI(Mainly on IOS).

[image]

Suggest me solution for these 2 problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to add a properties `LineBreakMode="NoWrap"` in the Label

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Tried LineBreakMode="NoWrap", but no change.

Comment: Frist of all, You can try to set the LineBreakMode="TailTruncation", if the label show the text like `Act...`

Comment: For the second issue, you can add `ColumnSpacing=5` in your `Grid` like following link .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#spacing

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I tried LineBreakMode and ColumnSpacing, no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question 1:You can change the Label code like following code.

```
  <Label 
      Text="{Binding title}"
      FontSize="Large"
      TextColor="Black"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      Margin="10,0,0,0"
      HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
      VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        />
```

For the second question, you can see this thread, Cole has test this issue in the IPhone 7 and IPhone 11, both of all them are Ok.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/173197/label-text-sometimes-showing-only-first-word-on-ui

Comment: Issue 1 is resolved, thanks.
I have tested on iPhone 7(12.4.1). But issue 2 still exists. Also on some android phones have this same issue.

Comment: Which resolutions Android phones did you test? I test it in the 1080X1920 420 dpi deivce is normal.

Comment: Now I replace the stack layout with a frame and remove the grid layout parts, now the second issue gets resolved.